# Problem in Converting Jupyter notebook to pdf

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tex, tex-live

When I want to save Jupyter notebook as a pdf file, I receive the following error:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex
? 
! Emergency stop.
<*> .\notebook
              .tex
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ?.
```

Comment: You should probably use `./notebook.tex`, not `.\notebook.tex`.

Comment: The error is made by the Jupyter notebook. I have just written some Python codes in Jupyter and when I want to save notebook as a pdf file, it shows me the error

Comment: @Werner The notice `! Undefined control sequence`, followed by the command in question, in this case `\notebook`, is LaTeX's way of telling the user, that they have not defined the command being called. Jupyter clearly tries to call said command when running LaTeX in order to create a PDF, but fails. This is because Jupyter's authors have not included this essential Jupter-specific command needed to produce PDFs. An oversight, probably.

Comment: Or maybe there's a Jupyter-related package included in either TeXLive or MikTeX, that @xuan has not installed?

Comment: @TheSodesa: I understand; I have some experience with LaTeX. This seems like a typo though...

Answer (score 1):

This is due to an unfortunate incompatibility between Windows and Unix-like systems. Jupyter creates a temporary `notebook.tex` document in the current directory and then calls `XeTeX` to compile this document.

`XeTeX` tries to parse the command line with roughly the following algorithm after being called:

1. `XeTeX <arg1> <arg2> ...`
2. Check if `<arg1>` is a `.tex` file,

   a) if it is a file compile it

   b) if it not a file assume this is the start of an actual document given on the command line

On Unix-like systems `./notebook.tex` is parsed by `XeTeX` into `current_directory/notebook.tex` which exists and is then compiled. On Windows systems the command line because of the different directory separator is `.\notebook.tex` which `XeTeX` does not recognize as a file and therefore tries and fails to parse as a LaTeX document.

A temporary remedy (could break other things) is to change the build directory in `pdf.py` from nbconvert (line 66) from

`writer = Instance("nbconvert.writers.FilesWriter", args=(), kw={'build_directory': '.'})`

to

`writer = Instance("nbconvert.writers.FilesWriter", args=(), kw={'build_directory': ''})`

Answer (score 0):

As an emergency solution, you can save the notebook as markdown (.md) and open it in RStudio, where you can Knit it and save it as pdf.